# How to search an array in Jquery like SQL LIKE %value% statement

Tags: jquery, arrays, search

I have an array with some values. How can I search that array using jquery for a value which is matched or close to it?

```
var a = ["foo","fool","cool","god"];
```

If I want to search for `oo`, then it should return `foo`, `fool`, and `cool` because these strings contain `oo`.

Comment: maybe http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: @3nigma that's for the contents of DOM elements. This is just a simple data structure.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

### Vanilla JS

To search in the array with Vanilla JS I would use the [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method implemented into the Array prototype.

*Note*: For **very** large arrays you might want to consider refactoring those to *async/await* functions else it might slow down the user interface.

#### 1. Using regular expressions (slower)

This is the most flexible approach as you could search for different patterns. You should be aware that the search term here is not a plain text, thus you have to escape most of non-alphanumeric chars according to the syntax. You should not pass unprocessed user input directly to the function, as it will not work as expected.

```js
let a = ["foo","fool","cool","god"];
var term = 'oo'; // search term (regex pattern)
var search = new RegExp(term , 'i'); // prepare a regex object
let b = a.filter(item => search.test(item));
console.log(b); // ["foo","fool","cool"]
```

#### 2. Using `indexOf` (faster)

In this particular case I would rather use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) which is basically an equivalent of `LIKE %term%` but much faster than using regular expressions when working with large arrays.

It is a common case to do case-insensitive searches so make sure to use `toLowerCase()` for both the search terms and the array items. Otherwise remove it everywhere from the examples.

```js
let a = ["foo","fool","cool","god"];
let term = 'oo';
let b = a.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(term) > -1);
console.log(b); // ["foo","fool","cool"]
```

#### ES6 style (ES2015)

```js
const fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

const filterItems = (needle, heystack) => {
  let query = needle.toLowerCase();
  return heystack.filter(item => item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0);
}

console.log(filterItems('ap', fruits)); // ['apple', 'grapes']
console.log(filterItems('ang', fruits)); // ['mango', 'orange']
```

#### ES5 style

```js
var fruits = ['apple', 'banana', 'grapes', 'mango', 'orange'];

function filterItems(needle, heystack) {
  var query = needle.toLowerCase();
  return heystack.filter(function(item) {
      return item.toLowerCase().indexOf(query) >= 0;
  })
}

console.log(filterItems('ap', fruits)); // ['apple', 'grapes']
console.log(filterItems('ang', fruits)); // ['mango', 'orange']
```

---

> *This is the outdated answer*
>
> To search in the array with jQuery you might use `jQuery.grep()` or
>   `jQuery.map()`. Both return new array with filtered elements using a
>   callback function.
>
> The fastest implementation (case insensitive) is using `indexOf` and
>   `toUpperCase` in the callback:
>
> ```
> var search_term = 'oo'; // your search term as string
> var search = search_term.toUpperCase();
> var array = jQuery.grep(a, function(value) {
>     return value.toUpperCase().indexOf(search) >= 0;
> });
> ```
>
> *If you don't need case insensitive search you can remove both `.toUpperCase()` to speed it up even further.*
>
> More flexible but much slower (good enough for small arrays) is to use
>   regular expression:
>
> ```
> var search_term = "oo"; // search term
> var search = new RegExp(search_term , "i");
> var arr = jQuery.grep(a, function (value) {
>     return search.test(value);
> });
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> var search_term = "oo"; // search term
> var search = new RegExp(search_term , "i");
> var arr = jQuery.map(a, function (value) {
>     return value.match(search) ? value : null;
> });
> ```
>
> *Regular expressions allow you to make searches much more complex than `%value%`. However don't use it if you don't need it because it is
>   many times slower.*
>
> you should get an array `arr` with the matched elements

Comment: how to pass variable instead of "oo" on search = /oo/gi; Is that like search = /my_var/gi; ?

Comment: should use `search = new RegExp(my_var, "gi");` /oo/gi is a shortcut of `new RegExp("oo","gi");` but be aware that `$.grep` and `$.map` cannot have extra params, so your `my_var` have to be defined in the global scope, which is not a good practice, but don't see other simple way

Comment: Thanks for your comment :) i have already found this solution http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/277324-need-help-on-jquery-array-match/ btw thanks again and rated you as Great Comment

Comment: Dear god, never use "gi" for Regex. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520800/why-regexp-with-global-flag-in-javascript-give-wrong-results

Answer (score 3):

```
function find(arr) {
    var result = [];

    for (var i in arr) {
        if (arr[i].match(/oo/)) {
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }

    return result;
}

window.onload = function() {
    console.log(find(['foo', 'fool', 'cool', 'god']));
};
```

It prints `["foo", "fool", "cool"]`

Answer (score 2):

Try the following js code

```
function likeMatch(q)
{
    my_arr = ["foo","fool","cool","god"];
    var rArr=[];

    for(var t in my_arr)
    {
      if(my_arr[t].indexOf(q)>0)   
      rArr.push(my_arr[t]);
    }
  return(rArr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
var infoData = ["foo","fool","cool","god"], 
search   = 'oo';

//this makes the magic
infoData = $$(infoData).filter(function(){
        return (this.search(search) >= 0)
    })  

var n = infoData.length;
    console.log("size result: "+ n );

for(var item = 0; item < n ;item++){
    console.log("item: "+item+" data : "+infoData[item]);       
}
```

result:

```
size result: 3

item: 0 data : foo
item: 1 data : fool
item: 2 data : cool
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with [Alasql](http://jsfiddle.net/0xs2nxxp/41/) JavaScript SQL library.
It supports LIKE operator, like in SQL

```
var a = ["foo","fool","cool","god"];
var searchString = "%oo%";

var res = alasql('SELECT COLUMN * FROM [?] WHERE [0] LIKE ?',[a, searchString]);
```

Try [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/0xs2nxxp/41/) at jfFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

try `$.inArray` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/. I'm not sure if it will allow you to use a regular expression but its worth a try

Answer (score 0):

use the following function if you are searching in array containing hashes object

```
 function searchInArrayofHashes(array,key,keyword) {
  responsearr = []
  for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
      if(array[i][key].indexOf(keyword) > -1 ) {
        responsearr.push(array[i])
    }
  }
  return responsearr
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use find method on array if you want to match any regex :

```
Array.find(x => /^left:/.test(x)
```