# Javascript string search not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have an array that contains some values. I want to be able to check if the value in the input field exists within the array. My code isn't returning anything now.

**Html**

```
<input type="text" id="str_search" value=" "/>
<input type="button" id="search_str" value="search" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var array = ["php", "jquery", "java"];
var src_keyword = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_str").click(function () {
        src_keyword = $("#str_search").val();
        // alert(find(array,src_keyword));
        find(array, src_keyword)
    });
});

function find(arr, src_keyword1) {
    var result = [];
    alert(src_keyword1);
    // src_keyword1="oo";
    for (var i in arr) {
        var search = new RegExp(src_keyword1, "gi");
        if (arr[i].match(search)) {
            alert(arr[i])
            result.push(arr[i]);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

thanks in advance

Comment: if you're iterating over the full list, why not use equality comparison?

Comment: i am not clear your word pls explain

Comment: I think he wants to be able to find an instance like **ffffjavaffff**

Comment: i followed this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324798/how-to-search-an-array-in-jquery-like-sql-like-value-statement

Comment: I'm not sure what is being asked here, if you have an array of strings and want to see if a value exists, it looks like an Array.indexOf solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fork:- http://jsfiddle.net/jfy8J/

Probably **why your code is not working is because you have a space** in the textbox value and you are not trimming it.

```
var array = ["php", "jquery", "java"];
var src_keyword = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_str").click(function () {
        src_keyword = $("#str_search").val().trim();
        var res = $.grep(array,function(obj,_){
            return obj === src_keyword;
        });
       if(res.length == 0) alert('not found'); else alert('found');
    });
});
```

**Update**
getting not found values :- http://jsfiddle.net/ELqZS/

```
var array = ["php", "jquery", "java"];
var src_keyword = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_str").click(function () {
        src_keyword = $("#str_search").val().trim();
       var items = $.grep(array,function(obj,_){
            return obj !== src_keyword;
        });
    alert(items);
    });
});
```

**Update 2** returns the items from the array that has the search text http://jsfiddle.net/8FJYS/

```
var array = ["php", "jquery", "java"];
var src_keyword = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_str").click(function () {
        src_keyword = $("#str_search").val().trim();
      var items =  array.filter(function(o, _){
            return o.indexOf(src_keyword) > -1;
        });
    alert(items);
    });
});
```

Comment: You want to return the not found values from the array?

Comment: Updated the fiddle to give you the items not matched from the array

Comment: ok i am confused. If the search text is contained in the array items return those items that contains the search text?

Comment: last doubt how to get array position

Comment: You mean where in array it exists?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RnFm3/ Check this, this should help, remember positions are zero based

Comment: if i am searching value return  php means  0, jquery => 1 java=>2

Comment: i run the code in firefox i am getting this error TypeError: o is undefined  if(o.indexOf(src_keyword) > -1)

Comment: I tried the fiddle in that only.. Is the fiddle working in FF?

Comment: I think one of your array values are undefined, you can use this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Phdc6/. This has a check

Comment: It's because of the for..in loop. array['php'], array['java'], array['jquery'] are all undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Change your for loop from

```
for (var i in arr)
```

to

```
for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++)
```

The former loop iterates over all the properties of the object as well as the value of each indexed element. For example

```
var a = [7,8,9,0];
a.blah = "aoeusnth";
for (var prop in a) {
    console.log(prop);
}
```

Will log

```
7
8
9
0
"blah"
```

to the console.

You are using the variable "i" to access the values of the array, but in your code "i" is the value already. What you want is to use the index of the item in order to access the item.

Comment: The former for loop will iterate over all the properties in the object, not just the elements in the array.

Comment: What does "sample problem" mean?

Comment: I'm sorry - I still don't understand. Are you asking a question?

Answer (score 0):

Just use .indexOf()

```
$("#search_str").click(function () {
  src_keyword = $("#str_search").val().trim();
  alert(array.indexOf(src_keyword) !== -1);
});
```

Comment: Adding .trim() should fix this.

Comment: when i am searching php return false

Comment: @Seenu I'm sorry the fiddle is old... here is the updated version http://jsfiddle.net/DV3a3/2/ : )

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the testing process. Right now, your testing the `result` strings for the `search` strings. You want to reverse that.

Use the regexp `test()` method. So...

```
var search = new RegExp(src_keyword1, "gi");
if(search.test(arr[i])){....}
```

Of course, you can now take the `RegExp` constructor out of the loop, among other small changes....

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [Array.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) rather than a regex solution.

> Summary
>
> Returns the first index at which a given element can be found in the
>   array, or -1 if it is not present.

```
<input type="text" id="str_search" value=" " />
<input type="button" id="search_str" value="search" />

var array = ["php", "jquery", "java"];
var src_keyword = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search_str").click(function () {
        src_keyword = $("#str_search").val().trim();
        alert(array.indexOf(src_keyword) !== -1);
    });
});
```

on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/2psp7/)