# jQuery/JavaScript operator equal SQL LIKE %Example%

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web

Is there any way to search a specific part on my input with Javascript/jQuery?

Tried to do with 2 different ways, but no results for that

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function () {

    $("#DivToToggle").toggle();
    var campo = document.getElementById('FieldToSearch');

    if (campo.contains("Test")) {
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "123";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "456";
    }
});
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function () {

    $("#DivToToggle").toggle();
    var field = document.getElementById('FieldToSearch');

    if (field.match(/Test.*/)) {
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "123";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "456";
    }
});
```

**@EDIT**

Thanks to @TalhaAbrar, found the correct way to do it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").click(function () {


    var field = document.getElementById('FieldToSearch').value;

    if (field.indexOf("Test")) {
        $("#DivToToggle").toggle();
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "123";
    }
    else {
        $("#DivToToggle").toggle();
        document.getElementById('FieldToWrite').value = "456";
    }
});
```

Comment: The problem is `FieldToSearch` is an HTML element - did you want the `text` property of it?

Comment: You can find answer to your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324798/how-to-search-an-array-in-jquery-like-sql-like-value-statement). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324798/how-to-search-an-array-in-jquery-like-sql-like-value-statement

Comment: @TalhaAbrar not really. That's about arrays, not Element objects

Comment: @tymeJV Yes, i want to search some text in this input. If have, do something. Else, do another thing

Comment: You need the `value` of that element when it is a form control

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros Try to fetch the value of search field like `document.getElementById('FieldToSearch').value` and then use function `indexOf` in your if statement, that should work for you.

Comment: Thanks to @TalhaAbrar! It works like a charm. Edited main post with functional code.

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros, glad to be of help, i have added my comment as an answer, kindly accept it as answer so that others can benefit from it as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to fetch the value of search field like `document.getElementById('FieldToSearch')`.value and then use function `indexOf` in your if statement, that should work for you.

example code:

```
var field = document.getElementById('FieldToSearch').value;

if (field.indexOf("value_to_check")) {
    // true if exists
} else {
    // false if doesn't
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check the value of the field, e.g.

```
var campo = document.getElementById('FieldToSearch').value;
...
```

And then use `includes()`, e.g.

```
if (campo.includes("Test")) {
...
```

Comment: It writes the "else" (456) option to FildToWrite

Comment: So what is the value of `campo`?

Comment: It should be the value of the html `<input>` element with the id `FieldToSearch`. @HudsonMedeiros can you show your HTML in your question?